# Корректны ли в Java записи подобного вида?

Tags: java

```
public static String 
    FrameTitle = "Заголовок окна",
    FrameLabel = "Лейбл окна",
    btn_1 = "Кнопка 1",
    btn_2 = "Кнопка 2",
    btn_3 = "Кнопка 3";
```

Приложение работает, но принято ли так писать в Java?
Просто для каждой переменной неудобно писать "public static String ...".
Но и запись

```
public static String FrameTitle = "Заголовок окна", FrameLabel = "Лейбл окна", btn_1 = "Кнопка 1", btn_2 = "Кнопка 2", btn_3 = "Кнопка 3";
```

смотрится нечитабельно.
Есть ли какие-то другие, может более правильные варианты?

Comment: Наример, Google Java Style Guide https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html запрещает это. См. п. 4.8.2.1.

Comment: Это больше вопрос личных предпочтений. Я, например, объединяю в "группу" только связанные между собой константы - как правило, эдакие мини-enum-ы. Вот что действительно не принято - так это писать названия полей с заглавной буквы. И вы осознанно написали `static` без `final`-а - это всё-таки не константы? И последнее - действительно ли эти значения должны быть `public`?

Comment: За замечания - спасибо.
Без `public` я ведь не доберусь до них из других классов? 
Эти строки у меня в отдельном классе, да и вообще все строки планирую создавать в нем - если вдруг придется их поменять не нужно будет искать их где то в коде.

Comment: По Google Java Style Guide - чтобы вытащить строчку, каждый раз придется обращаться ко всему массиву... интересно.. приму к сведению.

Comment: @Даниил если вам ответили в комментарии - можете просто попросить автора комментария скопировать текст ответ. Если не скопирует в течении дня-двух - смело постите как ответ сами, с примечанием "ответ дан в комментарии таким-то". Бесплатная репутация.

Comment: почитайте https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/

Comment: Если у вас отдельный класс для констант, то делайте интерфейс и объявляйте ваши константы в нем. В интерфейсе все поля имеют модификатор public static final, и это писать не придется.

Comment: @VladimirYarovoy спасибо. Попробовал, удобнее не придумаешь.
(как тут принято просить переписать коммент в ответ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если записи компилируются - то они корректны :) Вы можете в своем коде делать как угодно, если пишете сами и для себя. Дело вкуса. Если вы пишете open source, или в команде, то для дальнейшей поддержки Вашего кода другими программистами лучше придерживаться общепринятых норм, с которыми можно ознакомиться по запросу Java Code Conventions, например здесь: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf
Обозначать переменные принято каждую с новой строки.

Если у вас отдельный класс для констант, то делайте интерфейс и объявляйте ваши константы в нем. В интерфейсе все поля имеют модификатор public static final, и этот лишний текст для каждой строки писать не придется.